# Null check on more than one variable

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to reformat this piece of code in Kotlin, that it gets a bit smaller?
The function should return A and B as a Pair, if both are unequal to null. Else it should return null. My first idea was like this:

```
private fun <A, B> zip(a: A?, b: B?): Pair<A, B>? =
    if (a != null && b != null)
        a to b
    else
        null
```

Then I decided to use the Elvis Operator. So it now looks like this:

```
private fun <A, B> zip(a: A?, b: B?): Pair<A, B>? {
    a ?: return null
    b ?: return null
    return a to b
}
```

But what I am looking for is just something like this:

```
private fun <A, B> zip(a: A?, b: B?): Pair<A, B>? = 
    // This code obviously doesn't compile but is their any way to do it similar to this?
    a, b ?: return null
    return a to b
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No built-in function does this but you can write your own function to do that, e.g. `ifAllNotNull(vararg params: Any?, block: () -> Unit)`.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ok thats a good Idea but then the compiler doesn't know that a and b are not null

Comment: Your first block of code is the best possible way to do this, in my opinion, even if there are more concise ways. It is extremely clear and readable. But I would avoid calling it `zip` since that is a standard library function with a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

One fairly concise option is to create the Pair and then filter it:

```
(a to b).takeIf{ a != null && b != null }
```

But this isn't very good: it'll sometimes create a Pair unnecessarily, and the result type will have the Pair params both nullable, even though you know they can't be.

You could write an extension function to make it simpler.

Otherwise, I don't think you can do better than:

```
if (a != null && b != null) a to b else null
```

which is slightly longer-winded but has better efficiency and stricter typing.